# iPhone memory not released after view unloads and dealloc, why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have been struggling with memory issues in my  iphone app since weeks and haven’t been able to resolve the issue yet in spite of comprehensive research online.

Here is the case:
My application communicates with the Google Analytics API and is based on 3 basic views: Main view, setup view, and a tableview view that presents the data from google (with a custom cell). I have also constructed a custom class that fetches the data from google and then kills itself when done. All the data is stored in a singelton datacenter.

All views are initiated and then released as follows:

```
if (self.vVisitsTabelView == nil) {
    visitsTabelView *initiatevisitsTabelView = [[visitsTabelView alloc]     initWithNibName:@"visitsTabelView" bundle:nil];
    self.vVisitsTabelView = initiatevisitsTabelView;
    [initiatevisitsTabelView release];
}

[self.navigationController  pushViewController:vVisitsTabelView animated:YES];
[vVisitsTabelView release];
vVisitsTabelView = nil;
```

The issue is that through every loading of the view memory increases, but when the view is popped it is not releasing memory although dealloc is being called and ALL instance variables are being released. This cycle happens over an over again (while re-loading the same view) and memory consumption becomes very high. After demanding use I even got to 200mb real memory and 320 virtual on instruments. Strangely a memory warning was received only once, however my app never crashed due to low memory and instruments indicates NO leaks.

After entering background the memory is slowly being released and used by other apps, however when I return to foreground memory is reclaimed back to the level before entering background (maybe form the virtual mem?). This process takes 9 seconds and in that time the app is frozen.

Any ideas how to attack this situation? I have searched everywhere and carefully followed all guidelines.

Any lead is highly appreciated...

Please excuse me if I didn’t follow guidelines, this is my first time on this wonderful place.

Answer (score 2):

> Thank you, can you elaborate slightly more how to do it?

Yes;  you have a memory leak.  Now, the Leaks instrument may or may not tell you what is leaking.  It won't detect objects that are still somehow connected to the rest of the application;  i.e. if a reference to the object is retained in an NSMutableDictionary somewhere that is still in use by the app, it won't be detected.

Since you know exactly which object is being leaked, it is a matter of figuring out what has retained it, but not released it.   The Allocations instrument provides for exactly this capability.  Specifically, you can configure the Allocations instrument to track retain counts.

This article may help http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/.

Also, there are a number of very similar question/answers on SO that address this.  There is one in the last couple of weeks that I can't find that gave a great pictorial tutorial of how to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you! you have now provided me with a handful of weekend plans ;)

Answer (score -3):

Have you checked the retain count on your views? [theView retainCount] will do this.

Either way you should strongly consider moving to ARC which is new for iOS5. You should be able to say goodbye to all your memory management woes.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply... Will moving to ARC effect older IOS versions compatibility? lets say IOS 3.3?

Comment: ARC can only be used on iOS 4.3 and above so you'd have to drop support for iOS3 and older versions of iOS4.

Comment: The retainCount is useless.  Use the allocations instrument to determine what has retained, but not released, the object.

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate slightly more how to do it?